# Parse Julian Date in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I convert the function, `CAST(CAST(Column1 AS CHAR(7)) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYYDDD')` from Teradata to BigQuery as `FORMAT_DATE('%E4Y%j',PARSE_DATE('%E4Y%j',CAST(Column1 AS STRING)))` where Column1 is DECIMAL in TD so NUMERIC in BQ. If Column1 has value '2020280' in BQ, I get 2020001 in parse results but I need it to be '2020280'. Where do I go wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`PARSE_DATE` [does not support](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) `%j`. Use DATE_ADD as a workaround:

```
select FORMAT_DATE(
    '%E4Y%j',
    DATE_ADD(
        PARSE_DATE('%E4Y', LEFT('2020280', 4)),
        INTERVAL (CAST(RIGHT('2020280', 3) AS INT64) - 1) DAY
    )
);
```